# Loop through a table and insert its recordset into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below is a simplified example of what I want to do:

Table Fruits - Columns: FruitID and FruitName
Current table content:

```
1     Apple
2     Orange
3     Melon
```

I have another (empty) table which I want to INSERT rows like this: (let's say there's only one column named DateAndFruit)

```
2017-06-12 # Apple
2017-06-12 # Orange
2017-06-12 # Melon
```

I can easily use the date as input but for each fruits existing in Fruits table, I want to have a loop for insertion. This way, insertion is not soft-coded and I can add/remove fruits in the table and the insertion only focuses on what exists.

How can I build this transaction? I can build the loop but who can I read the 'next' row in Fruits table during iteration?

I think I can use temp tables but I guess there should be a better solution?

Comment: I still don't quite understand why you want to use a loop. Sql works best with a set based approach, I would suggest not to use loops.

Comment: `insert into empty_table (the_column) select current_date || ' # ' || fruitname from fruits`

Comment: One would usually *not* combine a date and a text in a string, but rather have two different columns. One would also usually *avoid* to have the name in two different tables. But generally it is an insert select you are looking for as just shown by a_horse_with_no_name.

Comment: Thanks for comments - I use MSSQL. I thought I'd receive comments on cursors? Also, This insert is not going to be a one time thing, that's why I need to use iteration.

Comment: The little voice in my head tells me not to ask, but ... . What are you _really_ trying to do that makes you certain that a cursor is the answer? `insert into`/`select` works quite well for multiple columns, e.g. `insert into Consumers ( FruitName, FruitbatName ) select Food, Eater from Vegans where FoodType = 'fruit' and EaterType = 'bat';`. There are times when a cursor is the appropriate tool, but less often than one might think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do like this.....

```
insert into table
(Name)
select convert(varchar(10),Date)+'#'+FruitsName from Fruits
```

Comment: i m giving answer for sql server

Comment: Wow, I had no idea it would be so easy - Thanks!

Comment: The response works but if I have additional rows to insert and populate, the SELECT used in INSERT breaks. Is there another way or should I go for INSERT and then UPDATE?

Comment: Hi Ravi, your reply works for simple inserts (which is what I asked in my provided example) but when things get complicated (such as multi columns and such), it does not. I found this link and applied it in my case: it works as I needed. [link](http://stevestedman.com/2013/04/t-sql-a-simple-example-using-a-cursor/)  Thank you!

Comment: Its your decision to use cursor, i will not use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below :

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE 
    v_fruit varchar2(50);
  p_date DATE NOT NULL := SYSDATE;
  CURSOR c1 IS
        select fruitname
           from tempaa;
BEGIN

      FOR c1_rec IN c1
      LOOP
                v_fruit :=c1_rec.fruitname;


                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Fruit name' ||' '||v_fruit);
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Delta DATE' ||' '||p_date);

            Insert into tempb(dateof, fruit)
                        values(p_date, c1_rec.fruitname);
           COMMIT;
      END LOOP;
      COMMIT;
      END;
```

Comment: The provided code did not apply to MSSQL but it helped me to search deeper on cursors. Found this link and it works in my case: http://stevestedman.com/2013/04/t-sql-a-simple-example-using-a-cursor/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
INSERT INTO EMPTY_TABLE
SELECT to_char(current_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
 || ' # '|| fruitname  FROm FRUITS;
```